# Delphi 7 ODBC MySQL Win 7

Tags: mysql, delphi, odbc

I seem to be going around in circles never getting this to go.
I have found a mySQL 5.1 32bit that installs and I have made a Schema and table
I also found a ODBC 5.1 connector That I installed.
Found dll's with start button editor - libmysql.dll dbexpmysql.dll  dbxopenmysql50.dll  myodbc5w.dll
Started Delphi 7 and DB express connector on form
Prams
Host name - Localhost.
Database - site.
Username - root.
Password - admin.
rest is default
I have tried all the above dll's
Error - unable to loadlibmysql.dll or the Dll I have selected in LibaryName.
This is a clean computer basically
What am I doing wrong 
I have checked my prams and remembered I set MySQL to localhost - 3306 in my settings as localhost is in google chrome is the ISS start page
This is a standalone computer, am I missing a update some where and if where do I get it from.
I have looked at other databases on my other computer like NoMySQL, oracle but they do not install on my messy computer easily for a standalone DB.

Comment: Do yourself a favor: Read this rambling wall of text with the vague, meaningless problem description and steps you've taken from our viewpoint, knowing nothing about the issue other than what you've written here. Then [edit] your post, use real words and sentences, with some paragraph breaks, punctuation, and a clear description of what you've done. (What in the world does *Found dll's with start button editor* even mean?) If you can't clearly state the question in a way that we can read and understand it, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at my answer to this q:

[how to connect to a MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883505/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-server)

It's about getting MySql working with D7 and XE5/6.  At the time I wrote it, I was having problems getting MySql to work with any of these Delphi versions.  It turned out that the main problem was that I was using too recent a version of the MySql Dlls.  I got it working eventually, but took me days and that's why I decided to record the exact method for posterity.

If you follow the exact numbered steps in that answer, I think that there is a pretty good chance that you will end up with a MySql set-up that has at least a chance of working with D7 (note in particular that I had to dig things out of the Archive section of MySql's website).

**Update**

Below are some extracts from my dbxDrivers.Ini & dbxConnections.Ini
and my Delphi test project

dbxDrivers.Ini

```
[Installed Drivers]
DB2=1
Interbase=1
MySQL=1
Oracle=1
Informix=1
MSSQL=1
OpenMySQL50=1

[OpenMySQL50]
LibraryName=dbxopenmysql50.dll
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverMYSQL50
VendorLib=libmysql.dll
HostName=localhost
DataBase=MATestDB
User_Name=SA
Password=password
[...]
```

dbxConnections.Ini

```
[OpenMySQL50Connection]
DriverName=OpenMySQL50
HostName=LocalHost
Database=MATestDB
User_Name=sa
Password=password
BlobSize=-1
```

Code

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection;
    SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery;
    DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider;
    SQLQuery1Table1ID: TIntegerField;
    SQLQuery1AName: TStringField;
    SQLQuery1AValue: TStringField;
    CDS1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure OpenConnection;
  public
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.OpenConnection;
begin

  SqlConnection1.DriverName := 'OpenMySql50';
  SqlConnection1.Params.Append('HostName=localhost');
  SqlConnection1.GetDriverFunc := 'getSQLDriverMYSQL50';
  SqlConnection1.LibraryName := 'dbxopenmysql50.dll';
  SqlConnection1.VendorLib := 'libmysql.dll';
  SqlConnection1.Params.Append('Database=MATestDB');
  SqlConnection1.Params.Append('User_Name=sa');
  SqlConnection1.Params.Append('Password=');
  SqlConnection1.Open;
  SqlQuery1.Open;
  CDS1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpenConnection;
end;
```

Those are all the relevant details of my D7 project.  After posting my earlier answer to the other q, I decided it was easier to have the two dbx .Ini files and the two Dlls in the same directory as my D7 project.

dbxopenmysql50.dll is dated 21 August 2007 and is version 1.3.0.39

libmysql.dll is dated 6 Octber 2006 and is 2,596,864 bytes.  There is no embedded version number.

My MySql server is version 5.6.19.  Obviously, you need to make sure the server is properly installed and that the MySql Server service is running.

As you can see, it works without involving ODBC.

If you get that far and are still having problems, I suggest you spend some time improving your q as Ken White suggested.

Comment: What did you use as a reference, and what dll's did you use to get your connection please MartynA.   I have just realized I did not register MySQL in the windows 32bit OBDC that I now have called it mySQL site. And noted no better results. many people talk of connection strings when Delphi has prams that i do not understand

Comment: Can I be blocked through my user account some how. is their part of the ODBC that needs to be set to everyone user accounts

Comment: dbxopenmysql50.dll will not load with my Delphi 7 DBexpress - why?

Comment: "dbxopenmysql50.dll will not load with my Delphi 7 DBexpress - why?" How on Earth could I know why it won't on your system.  I will add some more detail to my answer later.  Btw, I didn't need to use ODBC to connect to my MySql db on my system.

Comment: "What did you use as a reference, and what dll's did you use to get your connection"  I didn't use a reference:  I used my basic knowledge of dbExpress, the articles in the other q and a lot of googling and a lot of trial and error.  The DLLs are as stated in my answer to the earlier q.

Comment: SqlConnection1.DriverName := 'MySQL site'; // ODBC user data sources - name
  SqlConnection1.Params.Append('HostName=localhost'); //TCP/IP
  SqlConnection1.GetDriverFunc := 'getSQLDriverMYSQL50'; // default in delphi
  SqlConnection1.LibraryName := 'dbxopenmysql50.dll'; //delphi driver
  SqlConnection1.VendorLib := 'libmysql.dll';  // supplied by MySQL
  SqlConnection1.Params.Append('Database=site'); //  MySQL Database Name
  SqlConnection1.Params.Append('User_Name=root');  // ODBC user data sources - Name
   SqlConnection1.Params.Append('Password=pw'); //ODBC user Data sources - pw

Comment: some how stack overflow delayed showing your comments - I cannot get Delphi to accept dbxopenmysql50.dll no matter what I do. I have tried to identify the source of the information I'm using.

Comment: I have checked all I can think of to get this dll to load Visibility to Delphi through files, all the above files, ODBC. I just found my windows user account was blocking dbxopenmysql50.dll what else should I consider

Comment: " I just found my windows user account was blocking dbxopenmysql50.dll"  So, what have you done to unblock it?

Comment: Btw, you seem to persist in asking questions about your system which nobody else could possibly answer.  You haven't even said what OS you are using.  I'll say this one last time:  what I have stated in my answers to  this and the other q works without getting involved with ODBC **at all**.  Best I can suggest is try to get it working **without** ODBC and only try ODBC once you have.

Comment: Win 7 is my OS, I have got dbxopenmysql50.dll to load by opening Secpol.msc and getting the administrator account stared and running Delphi in administrator and ODBC re setup. Now Delphi is stating "unable to load libmysql.dll". As the libmysql.dll is from MySQL 5.1 version and in the same folder as dbxopenmysql50.dll. So the only solution is a compatibility issue of libmysql.dll as some people have stated. Yes this is frustrating/time consuming to get through.